# Add Indexed (Duplicated OK) to access database C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an application which inserts large amount of data in Access database.
So to speed up the things i have set Indexed property to No.

So at the end of insertion i need to set the index to the column of the one of the table to Indexed (Duplicates OK) through C#.

I tried:

```
string addIndex = "CREATE INDEX columnName ON table(columnName) WITH IGNORE NULL";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(addIndex, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but it didn't work.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try not using the column name as the index name: `CREATE INDEX idx_columnName ON table(columnName) WITH IGNORE NULL`

Comment: Hi @DStanley would you mind posting that as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using the column name as the index name:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_columnName ON table(columnName) WITH IGNORE NULL
```

Access may not let you name an index the same as an existing column (or table)